# Firebase Callable Cloud Function returning undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm creating a callable cloud function which creates a users profile in the cloud firestore db and also add custom claims...
I call it in the front-end as follows

```
 let setUpUser = functions.httpsCallable('setUpUser');

...other code

.then(async ()=>{
 try {
     const user = await setUpUser({
       displayName: this.state.name,
       email: user.user.email,
       type: this.state.type,
       organization: this.state.organization
     });
     console.log(user);
 }
 catch (e) {
   console.error(e);
 }
})
```

and the in the cloud function I try call the cloud function and set it up using the code below

```
exports.handler = ((data,context,admin,db )=>{
  let uid = context.auth.uid;
  return db.doc('users/'+uid).set({
      displayName:data.displayName,
      email: data.email,
      type:data.type,
      organization:data.organization
    })
  .then(()=>{
    if (data.type === "teacher"){
      return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid,{
        isTeacher:true,
      })
    }
    return;
  })
  .then(() => {
    return admin.auth().getUser(uid).then((userRecord)=>{
      return userRecord
    })
  })
  .catch(error =>{
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(error);
  });
})
```

But the log in the front-end is  `Cannot read property 'user' of undefined`

Comment: Add a `return user` statement to your function

Comment: @Scarysize Where should I that on the function?

Comment: Have you tried logging the values of everything in the Cloud Function to make sure it's working with the data you expect?

Comment: Also I can't help but notice that this code allows anyone to become a teacher, if they just know how to invoke it.